# Pandas: Apply custom function to groups and store result in new columns in each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to apply a custom function to each group in a groupby object and store the result into new columns in each group itself. The function returns 2 values and I want to store these values separately into 2 columns in each group.

I have tried this:

```
# Returns True if all values in Column1 is different.
def is_unique(x):
    status = True
    if len(x) > 1:
        a = x.to_numpy() 
        if (a[0] == a).all():
            status = False
    return status

# Finds difference of the column values and returns the value with a message.
def func(x):
    d  = (x['Column3'].diff()).dropna()).iloc[0]
    return d, "Calculated!"

# is_unique() is another custom function used to filter unique groups.
df[['Difference', 'Message']] = df.filter(lambda x: is_unique(x['Column1'])).groupby(['Column2']).apply(lambda s: func(s))
```

But I am getting the error: `'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment`

I don't want to reset the index and want to view the result using the `get_group` function. The final dataframe should look like:

```
df.get_group('XYZ')


   -----------------------------------------------------------------
   |   Column1 | Column2 | Column3  |  Difference   |    Message   |
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
   | 0   A     |   XYZ   |   100    |               |              |
   ----------------------------------               |              |
   | 1   B     |   XYZ   |    20    |      70       |  Calculated! |
   ----------------------------------               |              |
   | 2   C     |   XYZ   |    10    |               |              |
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need:

```
def func(x):
    d  = (x['Column3'].diff()).dropna()).iloc[0]
    last = x.index[-1]
    x.loc[last, 'Difference'] = d
    x.loc[last, 'Message'] = "Calculated!"
    return x

df1 = df.filter(lambda x: is_unique(x['Column1']))

df1 = df1.groupby(['Column2']).apply(func)
```

Comment: I am getting this error though: TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Comment: @Animeartist - Hmm, reason is ouput is DataFrame with same index like original `df`, seems in your solution is converted `Column2` to index. So maybe need `df = df.filter(lambda x: is_unique(x['Column1'])).groupby(['Column2']).apply(func).set_index('Column2')`

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, but unfortunately I am still getting the same error though.

Comment: `df = df.filter(lambda x: is_unique(x['Column1'])).groupby(['Column2']).apply(func).set_index('Column2')`. This line is returning the error.

Comment: @Animeartist - Hard to know what is error, because cannot run your sample data. So can you post `is_unique` for possible test it?

Comment: @Animeartist - also if check `print (type(df))` before `df.filter(lambda x: is_unique(x['Column1']))` it is `DataFrame` ?

Comment: @Animeartist - If I use `print (df.filter(lambda x: is_unique(x['Column1'])))` it return `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`

Comment: @Animeartist - answer was edited how should it working, but not 100% sure if understand it.

Comment: Hi, yes df is a DataFrame. I tested the code, and now I am getting this error: `AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'duplicated'`

Comment: @Animeartist - Not understand, if `print (type(df))` is DataFrame, how possible return error `SeriesGroupBy` ? It has to be groupby object, not Dataframe for this error.

Comment: Hi, Apologies for the mistake. df is actually `<class 'pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy'>`.

Comment: I am doing the entire process on df, which is a single group from another groupby object.

Comment: @Animeartist - Ya, is possible post some sample data and expected ouput after run this both functions? Because I try soemthing and failed. Also why it is `groupby` object?

Comment: @Animeartist - answer was edited, I crete 2 rows - first is for `is_unique` (this not underdtand) and then solution for new columns per groups.

Comment: Hi, thank you, its working correctly, but now the message and difference value is repeated for each row of the group instead of coming just once as denoted in the question.

Comment: @Animeartist - yes, so logic is add output for second row per groups? And if not exist second row?

Comment: Is it possible to merge the values of difference and message into one cell respectively?

Comment: @Animeartist - I am lost, please change data for see it. merge means join both values converted to strings? Or tuples? Or soemthing else?

Comment: @Animeartist - why is assigned only second row by 70 and `Calculated!`?

Comment: Hi, please see the edits. Right now, 70 and `Calculated` is repeated thrice for each row. But I want to merge them into only one single entry as shown in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230799/discussion-between-jezrael-and-animeartist).